# Explicit DG time step restriction for compressible Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: time-integration, navier-stokes, discontinuous-galerkin

Hesthaven's book [1](https://books.google.co.in/books?hl=en&lr=&id=0fNte_5nQNwC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=hesthaven+nodal+dg&ots=V9UKV414RW&sig=73TnIMATJCntMHTymgfWskofD_g&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=hesthaven%20nodal%20dg&f=false) mentions the following time step restriction for Navier-Stokes equations (see (7.32) in 2008 edition)
$$
\Delta t \approx \frac{h}{N^2} \frac{C}{|u| + |c| + \frac
{N^2 \mu}{h}}
$$
($h$-element size, $N$-degree of polynomial basis, $C$-constant)

Isn't this equation dimensionally incorrect? $\mu/h$ doesn't have dimensions of $u$. I think $\mu$ should be replaced by the kinematic viscosity $\nu$. However, there is nothing mentioned about this in "corrections" either ([2](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/%7Eapek/DGFEMCourse/Material.php),[3](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/jansh/page16/page21/assets/NDG-FEM-Misprints.pdf)).

Can anyone help me with giving the correct form of this?

### Edit

$\Delta t$ - time step

$h$ - characteristic element size (usually radius of inscribed or circumscribed circle)

$N$ - degree of polynomial approximation

$C$ - constant, $O(1)$

$u$ - fluid velocity in $x$ direction

$c$ - speed of sound

$\mu$ - dynamic viscosity

$\nu$ - kinematic viscosity

Comment: In my experience a lot of times dimensionful factors are used, and if they are set to 1 they are left out completely. Maybe this is one of those cases?

Comment: I think that might not be the case here. Time step restriction for a purely diffusive problem is $O(h^2/\nu)$. So I feel having $\nu$ in the expression is more natural.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I have edited my post to include description of the symbols

Comment: I haven't checked everything, but I think you're missing the fact that $N$ effectively has dimensions of 1/length, at least for the purposes of a time step condition.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I don't think so. Here $N$ is just the degree of polynomial approximation, a number. For instance, in pure advection flows, it is a common practice in DG methodology to divide the finite volume stable time step by $(2N+1)$ to get the corresponding DG value.

Comment: I understand why you think that; that's why I made the comment.  Unfortunately, I don't think an SE comment section is an adequate space to explain.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thank you for keeping this active. Please direct me to any references then :). I don't have the required math background to thoroughly understand Hesthaven's book and hence  am seeking help here.